# LightGBM: How to obtain the categorical_feature equivalent?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, data-science, lightgbm

I am using the LightGBM feature to transform the categorical variables I have.There is an example of a cat variables of a df:

| model | vehicle |
| --- | --- |
| Vespa | Motorbike |
| Tesla | Car |
| Ford | Car |
| Mustang | Car |

Some code I used to train the model was:

```
# Create a list with the categorical variables.

   categorical_vars = ["model", "vehicle"]

# TrainLightGBM model.

    clf= lgb.LGBMClassifier(max_depth=4)

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train,categorical_feature=categorical_vars)
```

When I obtain the digraph tree, I obtain the rules that the model applied to predict. By the way, it appears: **model=1**, and then, Yes or No. **How can I know to which model the 1 refers?**